# Building dependencies with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm new to CMake and I'm trying to figure out how to build dependencies. My project folders are organized like this:

```
Scrubber
 -- FileIO
 -- CDEs
 -- Utilities
 -- Scrubber
```

FileIO, CDEs, and Utilities are static libraries that are used by the executable in Scrubber.

I want to be able to execute a single make command from the top dir that will build everything. If I build each library independently, then it all comes together fine when I execute the top make. But if I don't do that it ahead of time then it won't build the dependencies and, not surprisingly, complains that the libraries weren't found.

So very simple question: how do I cause the system to build the libraries?

TOP LEVEL CMAKELISTS IN SCRUBBER

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Scrubber)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(FileIO)
add_subdirectory(CDEs)
add_subdirectory(Utilities)
add_subdirectory(Scrubber)
```

FILEIO CMAKELISTS IN SCRUBBER/FILEIO

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(FileIO)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp)

add_library(FileIO STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Don't prepend with "lib"
set_target_properties(FileIO PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

CDES CMAKELISTS IN SCRUBBER/CDES

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(CDEs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/lib/boost_1_60_0")

include_directories( ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR} )

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp)

add_library(CDEs STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Don't prepend with "lib"
set_target_properties(CDEs PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

UTILITIES CMAKELIST IN SCRUBBER/UTILITIES

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Utilities)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/lib/boost_1_60_0")

include_directories( ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR} )

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp)

add_library(Utilities STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Don't prepend with "lib"
set_target_properties(Utilities PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

SCRUBBER CMAKELIST IN SCRUBBER/SCRUBBER

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Scrubber)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/lib/boost_1_60_0")
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR "..")

include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_library(FILEIO_LIB FileIO.a HINTS ../FileIO/)
find_library(CDES_LIB CDEs.a HINTS ../CDEs/)
find_library(UTILITIES_LIB Utilities.a HINTS ../Utilities/)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp)

add_executable(Scrubber ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Scrubber ${FILEIO_LIB} ${CDES_LIB} ${UTILITIES_LIB})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
target_link_libraries(Scrubber ${FILEIO_LIB} ${CDES_LIB} ${UTILITIES_LIB})
```

if you have library `add_library(FileIO STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})`, then you should
write:

```
target_link_libraries(Scrubber FileIO )
```

cmake find out that this is also target, and create make file with proper dependencies, and you not have to point any dependencies with `add_dependency`,
cmake do it for automatically. At least current for me cmake version 3.5

Answer (score 0):

CMake includes the [add_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) command that does exactly what you need.

> Make a top-level  depend on other top-level targets to ensure that they build before  does.

Comment: In fact `cmake` can generate dependencies between top level target automatically, if they used in `target_link_libraries`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: I had originally tried that but couldn't make it work. If I add, for example, add_dependencies(Scrubber FileIO) to the top-level CMake file then it errors with "Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target." Am I putting it in the wrong place?